# Getting JSON info from PHP to android studio

Tags: php, android, json

This is my PHP code.

```
<?php
ini_set("display_errors", true);
ini_set("html_errors", false);
require "conn.php";
$query=mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM UserData");

if ($query){
    while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($query)){
        $flag[] =$row;


    }
    print(json_encode($flag));


}
mysqli_close($conn);
return $flag;
?>
```

This is how I tried to call it in android.

```
JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();
JSONObject jsonObjectTwo = jsonParser.getJSONFromUrlByGet("php-code");
```

Is this not how I call what the php code returns? ($flag)

Comment: You need to use something like okhttp to make the request. Look it up.

Comment: Please help me and explain to me how I would use okhttp in this situation.

Comment: This might help: http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JavaLibrary-OkHttp/article.html , but it's just one of those things you're going to have to hammer out.

Comment: Could you please share the result of  print(json_encode($flag));

Answer (score 0):

Follow the steps for Android.  Add dependency in your gradle

```
 compile 'com.loopj.android:android-async-http:1.4.9'
```

Request your web Api

```
    String url="Your url here";

    new AsyncHttpClient().get(url, new AsyncHttpResponseHandler() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, byte[] responseBody) {
          String rs = new String(responseBody);
           try{
           JSONArray array= new JSONArray(rs);
           for(int i=0;i<array.length();i++){
             String flag= array.get(i).toString;
           }

        }catch(Exception e){}
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(int statusCode, Header[] headers, byte[] responseBody, Throwable error) {

        }
    });
```